# Есть ли в C# аналог defer из Go

Tags: c#, golang

Есть ли в `C#` что-то наподобие `defer` из `Go`?

В `Go` можно было сделать так например:

```
func f() {
    defer return stack.Top(); // Указываем значение, которое нужно вернуть
    stack.Pop(); // Удаляем элемент. Но функция все равно вернет его значение
}
```

Comment: `try ... finally`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Удобство ```defer``` в том, что я могу указать возвращаемое из функции значение в начале кода, как в приведенном примере. С ```finally```, если я ничего не путаю, так не получиться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкретно для этого примера всё просто.

Эквивалент:

```cs
T MyFunc<T>(Stack<T> stack) // сигнатуру поменял для видимости, что к чему
{
    return stack.Pop(); // извлекает элемент из стека Stack<T> и возвращает значение
}
```

Что касается запоминания возвращаемого значения, то в этом нет необходимости. Обычно если значение результат вычисления известно, то его можно просто вернуть, и далее ничего не делать. Это как бы логично.

Но если очень надо, то обычный код без фокусов - вполне реальное решение.

```cs
T MyFunc<T>(Stack<T> stack)
{
    T result = stack.Peek();
    stack.Pop();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Да, я понимаю как написать обычный код) Спрашивал скорее из интереса, все-таки полезно знать всякие фичи языка, если они есть. Но спасибо за ответ!